# wxWidgets 3.0 - MSW application build does not start properly

Tags: windows, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I write an application of mine that is composed by main apps and libraries. I currently build it on Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows (Win7).

Since I updated wxWidgets libraries from v2.8 to v3.0, the Win build does not start anymore (the Linux one still works properly).

If I start the debugger in Windows, I see that the application process exits right after entering the `IMPLEMENT_APP` macro, with following kind of output:

```
[Inferior 1 (process 3516) exited with code 01]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I use Code::Blocks IDE, on Win7 64-bit.

Comment: Can you build and run the sample programs under windows?  Can you create an extremely small & simple windows app that exhibits this problem?

Comment: @ravenspoint: I created a "fake" new application that is linked to all the libraries of my app and calls a routine from each of them. It runs without problems.

Comment: You are on your own with this one.  You will need to do a binary search between the app that runs and the one that doesn't, subtracting code from the failing app until it starts to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding wxWidgets library and the whole application binaries with latest wxWidgets 3.0.1 cleared the issue.
Now the application works; I am not sure if this was due to a wrong configuration of my project files or to a wxWidgets bug.